# How to find out if an XML-RPC server is working?

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I have a huge Ping list and want to clean it.

Using PHP I have already removed duplicated, checked for 404s, redirects etc.

I was wondering what I could send to the URLs to see if they are actually functioning and open for submissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [XML-RPC Introspection](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/introspection.html) de facto standard which you could try first. If the server doesn't offer introspection you could just try to send a randomly generated method call. If it is a working XML-RPC Server you should get back a fault object.

Comment: Very good :) Using: http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/, and your suggestion is getting me back an object which is plenty. Thanks.